# WPF, Data Template width

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a data template formatting items in a ListBox

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChildViewModelTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FFDC1C1C" BorderThickness="1" >
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
            <Image Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="31" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/rocket.ico"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>                
</DataTemplate>
```

This puts a border around each item extending to the length of the text string bound in the TextBlock binding.

Is there a simple way to have all elements the same width, where the width is equal to the longest element? For bonus points I'm wondering if there is a way to do it for the longest visible element and/or longest element regardless if it's visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) and [SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx) Properties.
Here's a tutorial for it:
http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/johnbowen/archive/2007/08/27/21132.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Botz3000's answer. SharedSizeGroup is the way to go here. This will do it

```
<ListBox ...
         Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Col1"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="#FFDC1C1C" BorderThickness="1" >
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
                        <Image Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="31" Source="C:\C1.png"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is what I love about WPF so far, it doesn't feel like there's anything I can come up with that the designers haven't already thought of, and provided a solution to. The tutorial is excellent and gives me a bit of insight into RelativeSource as well, which I intended to look at next :)